# How to set feature layer with graphic feature set Android Arcgis

Tags: android, arcgis

I'm trying to fill a feature layer with graphics but have the problem that when using the FeatureLayer(graphics[]), instruction does not add the graphics to the feature layer. It shows the following

```
Error "method invocation may produce java.lang.nullpointerexception
```

I tried assigning a single value to the list level code does not generate any error and graphics list is filled correctly, or have any idea how that can fill a feature layer with a list of graphics?

I attached my code

```
MapView mMapView;
ArcGISFeatureLayer featurelayerpoints;
FeatureSet variablefeatureset = null;
Graphic[] graficos = new Graphic[listcount];

for (int i = 0; i < listcount; i++) {
    Point wgspoint = new Point(routesinfolist[i].Longitude, routesinfolist[i].Latitude);
    Point mapPoint = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(wgspoint, SpatialReference.create(4326),
        mMapView.getSpatialReference());
    Unit mapUnit = mMapView.getSpatialReference().getUnit();
    double zoomWidth = Unit.convertUnits(SEARCH_RADIUS, Unit.create(LinearUnit.Code.MILE_US), mapUnit);

    attributes.put(String.valueOf(routesinfolist[i].IDOrder), "IDOrder");
    graficos[i] = new Graphic(mapPoint, new PictureMarkerSymbol(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circler)), attributes, i);
}

variablefeatureset.setGraphics(graficos);
featurelayerpoints = new ArcGISFeatureLayer(null, variablefeatureset, null);
mMapView.addLayer(featurelayerpoints, 1);
```

Comment: And which line does the `NPE` show up on?

Comment: in this line  variablefeatureset.setGraphics(graficos);

Comment: Let me know if the answer solved your problem

Comment: thanks to one of the comments I could assign the variable but not achievement that the feature layer is displayed on the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presently, your `FeatureSet variablefeatureset` is set to `null`. You need to initialize it using the constructor provided. [[docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/map/FeatureSet.html#FeatureSet%28%29)]

```
FeatureSet variablefeatureset = new FeatureSet();
```

Comment: thanks, that was the right way to initialize the variable